# Convenient way to run multiple python interpreters on single machine. Can indicate interpreter path inside script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have 2 python scripts `A` and `B`. `A` uses `C:\python385\python.exe` as interpreter. `B` uses `C:\Anaconda\python.exe`. My objective is to double-click on the python file on Windows 10, then have the script run on the interpreter I want.

Is there a convenient way to indicate the interpreter path inside the script? I am welcome to other methods to achieve my objective.

I am using windows 10, python 3.8, anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On windows python launcher can do that using virtual [shebang lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines).

Just make sure all your python install locations are in your system's PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks. I thought shebangs are for linux systems. I didn't know windows supports shebang as well.

Comment: @user3848207 You are right, windows doesn't support shebang lines. It's the python launcher for windows that implements it.

Comment: when I double-click on the python file, does it automatically use the python launcher for windows?

Comment: @user3848207 Depends on the way you installed the python (there is python launcher installation option, checked by default). The installer associates .py/.pyw with the py.exe/pyw.exe laucnher. You can check in your windows' installation registry. It's usually in 
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Python.File\Shell\open\command

Answer (score 2):

[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can set up different interpreters for different projects.